# Processing. Cannot find a class or type named

Tags: error-handling, kinect, processing

I liked this processing sketch ( https://github.com/trentbrooks/Noise-Ink ).
When I launch this one as ready-to-use app - it's OK. But when i try it in processing i get such error - "Cannot find a class or type named 'Kinecter' " and processing select this line 'Kinecter kinecter;'. What's wrong with it?

Comment: import java.util.*; doesn't work

Comment: How many tabs do you have? You don't seem to have loaded the whole sketch... You are missing the 'Kinecter' class, thus the Kinecter.pde

Comment: Really i was missing kinecter.pde. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't happen to have the entire sketch itself, I looked into his thing and saw 5 tabs, you always want to make sure that you have every tab within a sketch, otherwise the program will not work and you will end up with many errors.